# Is there anything similar to C++ bind in Go?

Tags: go, callback

I'm trying to do something in Go, similar to C++'s bind.
**In C++ :**

```
class A {
public:
    typedef std::function<bool(const string&)> Handler;
    bool func(A::Handler& handler) {
        // getData will get data from file at path
        auto data = getData(path);
        return handler(data);
    }
};
```

In another class B:

```
Class B {
public:
    bool run() {
        using namespace std::placeholders;
        A::Handler handler = bind(&B::read, this, _1);
        m_A.initialize();
        return m_A.func(handler);
    }
    bool read(const string& data) {
        std::out << data << std::endl;
    }
private:
    A m_A {};
};
```

when B's run() function is called, it will bind class B member function read with A's Handler.
Then `m_A.func(hander)` is called, it will call `getData()`. The data got is then parsed to `B::read(const string& data)`

Is there any way to do it in Go? How to create a forwarding call wrapper in golang?

Comment: Functions are first-class types in Go: https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Solution:**

I'm posting my own solution for my question:

I am passing go function as a parameter of another function to do the callback. The following code is a go version of the above C++ code.

In `A.go`

```
type A struct {
    //... some properties
}

type Handler func(string) bool
func (a *A) ReadRecords(handler Handler) bool {
    // getData will get data from file at path
    auto data = getData(path)
    return handler(data)
}

func (a *A) Initialize() {
    //... Initialization
}
```

In `B.go`, A is a member of B struct

```
type B struct {
    a    A
    //...other properties
}

var read A.Handler
func (b *B) Run() bool {
    read = func(data string) {
        fmt.Println(data)
    }
    b.a.Initialize()
    return b.a.ReadRecords(read)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced a similar problem. Given:

```
func Method(f Foo, b Bar)
```

I wanted:

```
var binded : func(b Bar) = bind(Method, Foo{})
```

And eventually I just used this method:

```
func (f Foo) BindableMethod(b Bar) {
    return Method(f, b)
}
var binded = Foo{}.BindedMethod
```